# Use angular model data in script

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need some help with controller model data sharing.

In HTML I can access data by `{{block.title}}`, but also in html I have some javascript to open external file:

```
<div class="container">
    <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
        <accordion-group ng-repeat="block in report.blocks" is-open="block.$$isOpen">
        <accordion-heading>{{block.tags}}
        </accordion-heading>
        <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#includedContent").load("res/filename.html");
        });
        </script>
        <div id="includedContent"></div>
       </accordion-group>
   </accordion>
</div>
```

What I want is to use current value of `block.title` (inside of `ng-repeat`) in place of `filename.html` like:

`load("res/{{block.title}}.html")`.

How can I achieve that?

Thank you.

Comment: show your html.. It is quite simple.. you can do this using ng-model.

Comment: @Ved Updated in my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this in angular with relative ease, no jQuery needed.

```
<div id="includedContent" ng-include="getPartial(block.title)"></div>
```

In your controller

```
$scope.getPartial = function(file) {
    return "res/"+file;
};
```